# Laravel + Angular2-seed integration

Tags: laravel, angular

I am trying to integrate [angular-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) into an empty laravel application.

It seems that, by default, angular-seed looks for node_modules in the root level.

I have tried modifying some parameters in the config files, but there is always something that ends up breaking.

Does anybody have experience solving this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a repo for a with angular2 + laravel, you should be able to compare files and find the right configuration
https://github.com/moff/laravel5-angular2